# How can I change HTTP headers such as X-UA-Compatible in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, rack, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 pre-populates some "best practice" HTTP headers:

```
$ http -j "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
(...)
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
(...)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

How do I change these headers in Rails 4?

Comment: Fun fact: `http` is http://httpie.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to disable (or change) that, add the following line to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-Frame-Options' => 'DENY',
  'X-UA-Compatible' => 'IE=EmulateIE7'
}
```

Comment: I understand that you're trying to show how to change these fields, and therefore you put values that are different from the defaults. But given that people are likely to copy-and-paste this, I suggest not giving an example that could lead to security holes (e.g. turning off XSS protection).

Comment: Good catch @NickUrban, just updated the code example to be a little more secure by default.